# Duplicate Records move to other temp table in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using Pyspark

My Input Data looks like below.

```
 COL1|COL2
|TYCO|130003|
|EMC |120989|
|VOLVO|102329|
|BMW|130157|
|FORD|503004|
|TYCO|130003|
```

I have created DataFrame and querying for duplicates like below.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
     .builder \
     .appName("Test") \
     .getOrCreate()

data = spark.read.csv("filepath")

data.registerTempTable("data")
spark.sql("SELECT count(col2)CNT, col2 from data GROUP BY col2 ").show()
```

This give correct result but can we get duplicate value in seperate temp table.

```
output data in Temp1

+----+------+
|   1|120989|
|   1|102329|
|   1|130157|
|   1|503004|
+----+------+
```

output data in temp2

```
+----+------+
|   2|130003|
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT count(col2)CNT, col2 from data GROUP BY col2  having cnt > 1 ");
sqlDF.createOrReplaceTempView("temp2");
```